# Custom css overridden by Bootstrap in browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, stylesheet

I have my stylesheet directory set up like this

```
stylesheets
    bootstrap.min.css
    style.css
```

In my style.css, I want to edit the pre tag like this:

```
pre {
    background-color: #d9edf7;
    border: #d9edf7;
    color: navy;
}
```

However, this is not getting picked up in the browser. It seems like the browser is going with the styles in bootstrap.min.css. This is what it looks like in Chrome's inspector tools when I hover over the block of pre tag:

[image]

So how do I get it to use my custom css instead?

Comment: make sure you include your custom css after the bootstrap css!

Comment: @sebastianbrosch ahh, I see, now it works

Comment: @sebastianbrosch thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure you include your custom CSS after the Bootstrap CSS, like the following:

```
<head>
    <!-- don't include your custom CSS here! -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
    <style>
        pre {
            background-color: #d9edf7;
            border: #d9edf7;
            color: navy;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place `style.css` *after* `bootstrap.min.css`, so  `style` overrides `bootstrap`.