# Overriding Bootstrap CSS in Javascript

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overriding

How do you override a BootStrap CSS file? I have created another file called site.css and linked it to the index.html file; however, this still does not allow me to override. Is this not a correct action?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom css overridden by Bootstrap in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622595/custom-css-overridden-by-bootstrap-in-browser)

Comment: Is it linked below the Bootstrap one? Please show that. Also show what style you want to override and how you are trying to, and the current result. Tag me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to override the bootstrap CSS so you can try this trick.
put your bootstrap css and site.css in head section like below example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css">
```

now site.css will be override to bootstrap.css :)

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to override bootstrap is to create your own style class.

```
<div class="bootstrapclass yourownoverrideclass"></div>
```

in your css

```
.bootstrapclass.yourownoverrideclass {
    margin: 5px; //override content
}
```